# error on line 7 at column 374: xmlParseEntityRef: no name

Tags: php

i am getting that error while creating xml file in php.
cna you please tell me the solution to me

```
                 error on line 7 at column 374: xmlParseEntityRef: no name


                        header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");

                date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
                $content=$this->view->data=$this->CallModel('posts')->GalleryAndContent();
          $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
                            <rss version="2.0">
                            <channel>';                           
          $xml.='<title>Thehansindia</title>
                    <link>http://www.thehansindia.com</link>
                    <description>Newspaper with a difference</description>';   

            foreach($content as $k){
                        $data=strip_tags(stripslashes($k['text_data']),"<p><span><div>");

                        $data=preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $data);

                         $data=str_replace(array("<div>","</div>","<span>","</span>"),array("<p>","</p>","<p>","</p>"),$data);
                        $data= preg_replace('/<p>\p{Z}*<\/p>/u', '', $data); 
                         $data=str_replace("<p/>"," ",$data);
                        $data= preg_replace('/<p>\p{Z}*<\/p>/u', '', $data);
                            $data=str_replace( '<p>&nbsp;</p>', ' ', $data);
                        $data=str_replace( '&nbsp;', ' ', $data);
                        // $pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/"; 
                        // $data= preg_replace($pattern, '', $data);
```

/

```
                        $xml.= '<item>';
                        $xml.=" <storyid>".$k['id']."</storyid>"; 
                        $xml.=" <Headline>".$k['title']."</Headline>";
                        //$xml.="<content>".html_entity_decode($data)."</content>";
                        $dom = new DOMDocument;
                        @$dom->loadHTML($data);
                        $xml.="<CONTENT>";
                        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $tag){
                            if(!empty($tag->nodeValue)){ 


                            $xml.="<p>".$tag->nodeValue."</p>";

                            }
                            }



                        // $xml.="<CONTENT>".$VALUES['text_data']."</CONTENT>";
                            $xml.="</CONTENT>";
                            $xml.= '</item>';

    }


                      $xml.='</channel></rss> '; 
                      echo $xml;
```

this is my code .By using this i am displaying content of mysql in xml page.In that somany special chrs are there thats why i used html_entity_decode in that .can you please tell me that solution for me

Comment: I guess your problem happen at line `8`. Your code is invisible to me though.

Comment: please provide your code for better analysis

Comment: Definitely an error at line 8.

Comment: I edited the code @ Abhishek